# How to insert data into Oracle by using where not exists?

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

When I use this code, it returns an error "SQL command not properly ended" - what am I missing?

```
cmd.CommandText = "insert into trf_urun_bırım_detay " + 
    "values ('838', '1198385027', '950', '034') " +
    "where not exists(select * from trf_urun_bırım_detay where transfer_no = '838')";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL Statement is incorrect. You either have to use [`MERGE`](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=203) statement or change your sql statement to the following:

```
insert into trf_urun_bırım_detay (transfer_no , Field2, Field3, Field4) 
select '838','1198385027','950','034'
from dual where not exists(select * from trf_urun_bırım_detay where transfer_no = '838');
```

I have used `Field2,Field3,Field4` for your fields, because you didn't mentioned their names.